# React Route - cannot assign to "render" because it is not a variable

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here's a PrivateRoute I'm trying to make

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
    return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => <Component {...props} />} />
}
```

[image]

At `Route` and `{...rest}`, eslint throws `Parsing error: > expected`.

At `render=`, I get `Cannot assign to 'render' because it is not a variable` and for every other identifier after it, I get `unreachable code`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Validate your code with typescript. I don't know much more about typescript, someone could help you.

Comment: Can you check if your component filename ends with `*.tsx`, not `*.ts`?

Comment: Thanks @AjeetShah, it was a kill shot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @AjeetShah pointed out in the comments, the issue was with the file extension.

The file extension was `.ts` instead of `.tsx`.

Hope you don't make a mistake this silly!

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, All React component names must start with a `capital` letter. If you start a component name with a lowercase letter, it will be treated like a built-in element like a `<div>` or a `<span>`. This is because of the way JSX works.

Try to disable eslint in this file because I think eslint has been confused.

Add the below comment at top of your file.

```js
/* eslint-disable */
```

Comment: Are you serious? Just disable linting entire file because there can be something else that might be wrong?

Comment: 1. There is nothing that is wrong in your code 2. Maybe you wrote a bad character in your code which broke your code(I suggest you write that file's code from scratch if you agree on this idea). So, if you are sure that you didn't write any bad character, then the best way is to disable the eslint, Cuz I used your code into my project and everything works well with no eslint error.